# How to Center Logo in Responsive Header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, multiple-columns

Please watch as the page is scaled:

[image: picture 1]

[image: picure 2]

[image: picture 3]

[image: picture 4]

[image: picture 5]

[image: picture 6]

As you can see, the responsive header is working perfectly from mobile to tablet size, but then does not center from tablet to desktop. How can I get the image to center in pictures 5-6? I'm new to the 12-column grid system, so please enlighten me if you think that is what's causing the problem. Thank you!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Knights Basketball Academy</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="styles3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideimages = new Array(); // create new array to preload images
slideimages[0] = new Image(); // create new instance of image object
slideimages[0].src = "images/slider1.png"; // set image src property 
to image path, preloading image in the process

slideimages[1] = new Image();
slideimages[1].src = "images/slider2.png";
slideimages[2] = new Image();
slideimages[2].src = "images/slider3.png";
slideimages[3] = new Image();
slideimages[3].src = "images/slider4.png";

</script>
</head>

<body>

<header>
<div class="row">
  <!--first row-->
  <div class="col-12" "col-m-12">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo3.png" alt="logo" height="450" width="1130">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--ends first row-->
</header>


<div class="navigation">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index3.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="roster.html">Roster</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<div id="background"><!--background image-->
<div class="row"><!--second row-->

<div style="text-align:center"><!--image slider-->

<img src="images/slider1.png" id="slide" width="713" height="250" />

<script type="text/javascript">

//variable that increments through the images
var step=0;

function slideit(){
 //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
 if (!document.images)
 return
 document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src;
 if (step<3)
  step++;
 else
  step=0;
 //call function "slideit()" every 5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",5000);
}

slideit();
</script>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row"><!--third row-->

<div class="col-3 col-m-3">
<img src="images/image5.jpg" alt="Team Photo">
</div>

<div class="col-6 col-m-9" id="background2">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Knights Basketball Academy is a non-profit 
amateur basketball club focused on individual player development 
and team concepts.  With our elite coaching staff,  we are 
confident that all players can achieve their own maximum potential 
while maintaining excellent character and integrity. 
<br>
<br>
Contact us at info@knightsbasketballacademy.com to learn how to become a 
Knight today.</p>    

</div>

<div class="col-3 col-m-12">
<aside>
<h2>What?</h2>
<p>The KBA is a non-profit amateur basketball club focused on 
individual player development and team concepts. </p>
<h2>Where?</h2>
<p>We are located in St. Louis, Missouri. Practices are held at the 
 Des Peres Lodge.</p>
<h2>How?</h2>
<p>Visit our About page for more contact information.</p>
</aside>
</div>

</div><!--ends third row-->

<footer>
<p>&copy;2016 KNIGHTS BASKETBALL ACADEMY</p>
</footer>
</div><!--ends background-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.row:after{content:"";
       clear:both;
       display:block;}

[class*="col-"]{float:left;
            padding:10px;}

/*global styles*/ 

.knights {margin-top:0px}

.logo img {max-width:100%;
       height:auto;}

.banner {display: inline-block;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;}

.navigation {text-align:center;
         background-color:#000000;
         padding:0px;}

#banner {text-align:center;
     margin-bottom: 0px;}

#background {background-image: url("images/background.jpg");}

#background2 {background-color:white;}

a{text-decoration:none;
  color:white;}

a:visited {color:white;}

nav{margin:auto;
    height:auto;}

nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family:Arial;}

nav li {
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 background-color :#000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
 display:block;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-right:30px;}


nav li:hover {
 background-color: #8E8E8E;}

aside{background-color:#C5202A;
  padding:15px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.1em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);}

footer{background-color:#000000;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding:15px;}

img{max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}

/*mobile phones first*/
[class*="col-"]{
width:100%;
}

/*tablet*/
@media only screen and (min-width:600px)
{

/*12 column grid*/

.col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-m-3 {width: 25%; text-align:center;}
.col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-m-9 {width: 75%; background-color:white;margin-top:10px;}
.col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-m-12 {width: 100%;}

nav {height:auto;}

nav li {display:inline-block;}

}   

@media only screen and (min-width:768px)
{   

/*12 column grid*/

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%; text-align:center;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%; background-color:white;margin-top:10px;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}  

nav {height:auto;}

nav li {display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;}  

}


div.clear { clear:both;}
```

**EDIT**: The code for the logo can be found in the header (first row), under the div class "logo". I already tried "text-align:center" for the logo class. I don't know what else to try.

**EDIT2** Please, what I need help understanding is how to specify the style for the desktop size vs the style for the tablet size. For example, I may need margin-left: 100px in desktop but not in tablet or mobile. That's what I'm confused about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use translate like in this example.

```
    .center{
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Or you can use Media Queries.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

UPDATE

CSS

```
.center{
  margin-left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
  width: 80%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img class="center" src="images/logo3.png" alt="logo" height="450" width="1130">
      </a>
    </div>
```

codepin: http://codepen.io/kmathmann/pen/PZLdBz?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you. You were suggesting that I add the .center class to the img, right? Like this: <img class="center" src="images/logo3.png" alt="logo" height="450" width="1130">

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<header>
<center>
<div class="row">
  <!--first row-->
  <div class="col-12" "col-m-12">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo3.png" alt="logo" height="450" width="1130">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</center>
<!--ends first row-->
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Now I will just need to adjust the image in Illustrator.